# Docker changes owner of local files mounted as volume

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-volume, chown, owner

I cannot find anywhere answer why docker changes owner of files mounted as volume. Before `docker run`:

```
$ ls -la
total 56
drwxrwxr-x 9 ci ci 4096 Mar 13 21:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 ci ci 4096 Mar 13 21:12 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ci ci 1108 Mar 13 21:13 application.yml
drwxrwxr-x 5 ci ci 4096 Mar 13 21:13 ci
drwxrwxr-x 5 ci ci 4096 Mar 13 21:13 config
drwxrwxr-x 3 ci ci 4096 Mar 13 21:13 database
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ci ci 2779 Mar 13 21:13 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x 3 ci ci 4096 Mar 13 21:13 docker-stuff
drwxrwxr-x 8 ci ci 4096 Mar 13 21:13 .git
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ci ci  137 Mar 13 21:13 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ci ci 6366 Mar 13 21:13 image.sh
```

After `docker run`:

```
$ ls -la
total 60
drwxrwxr-x 10 administrator administrator 4096 Mar 13 21:15 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 ci            ci            4096 Mar 13 21:12 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 administrator administrator 1108 Mar 13 21:13 application.yml
drwxrwxr-x  5 administrator administrator 4096 Mar 13 21:13 ci
drwxrwxr-x  5 ci            ci            4096 Mar 13 21:13 config
drwxrwxr-x  3 administrator administrator 4096 Mar 13 21:13 database
-rw-rw-r--  1 administrator administrator 2779 Mar 13 21:13 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x  3 administrator administrator 4096 Mar 13 21:13 docker-stuff
drwxrwxr-x  8 administrator administrator 4096 Mar 13 21:13 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 administrator administrator  137 Mar 13 21:13 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr-x  1 administrator administrator 6366 Mar 13 21:13 image.sh
```

Full `docker run` command is:

```
docker run -d \
             --rm \
             --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" \
             -p "$SHINY_HOST_PORT:3838" \
             -p "$RSTUDIO_HOST_PORT:8787" \
             -v "$DATA_DIR_ON_HOST":"$DATA_DIR_IN_CONTAINER" \
             -v "$CONFIG_DIR_ON_HOST":"$CONFIG_DIR_IN_CONTAINER" \
             -v $(pwd):"/data/" \
             "$DOCKER_IMAGE":"$DOCKER_TAG"
```

My user groups are:

```
$ groups
ci sudo docker administrator
```

Do you have any ideas why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command which adds the [`--user` *docker run* option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) to control the *uid* and *gid* that will be used by the process running in your container:

```sh
docker run -d \
      --rm \
      --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" \
      -p "$SHINY_HOST_PORT:3838" \
      -p "$RSTUDIO_HOST_PORT:8787" \
      -v "$DATA_DIR_ON_HOST":"$DATA_DIR_IN_CONTAINER" \
      -v "$CONFIG_DIR_ON_HOST":"$CONFIG_DIR_IN_CONTAINER" \
      -v $(pwd):"/data/" \
      --user "$(id -u ci):$(getent group ci | cut -d: -f3)" \
      "$DOCKER_IMAGE":"$DOCKER_TAG"
```

---

- `id -u ci` will get the *uid* of user `ci`
- `getent group ci | cut -d: -f3` will get the *gid* of group `ci`

Answer (score 0):

The permission in the container run as root by default, so every time you mount a volume the permissions are reset to root. Refer [this](https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca) article.